# Comma Button after Pi

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

I'm building an RPN Calculator on Swift.

I want to disable the comma button, if there's already one in the display. For instance, with the PI.

The PI button works, but I need to disable the comma button after PI is pressed (as it already has a comma). Of course, once I hit ENTER or an OPERATION the comma has to be enabled again, and I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Here's the code for PI.

```
let Pi = round (M_PI * 100000000 ) / 100000000
@IBAction func PiPressed() {
       labelDisplay.text = "\(Pi)"

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

once you hit Enter or Operation button you could do the following to check weather the label contains a comma or not

```
if labelDisplay.containsString("."){
    commaButton.enabled = false
}
```

containsString will return true whenever the string contain the string argument you are passing

to enable the commaButton again all you need to do it

```
commaButton.enabled = true
```

you will do this line of code to enable the comma when you start writing a new number

hope this help.

Comment: please let me know if you need any help. Thanks.

Comment: If I addressed your question, please mark my answer as such.